# IoT Edge support for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: azure-iot-edge

any news on when Ubuntu 20.04 LTS will be a supported OS for IoT Edge?
I have looked at the documentation but couldn't see anything.
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 20.04 would be a [Tier 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/support#tier-2) OS. The Debian 9 packages from the Azure IoT Edge releases [repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iotedge/releases) should work out of the box with Ubuntu 20.04.